# Reading a CSV file into Java as a DB table

Tags: java, jdbc, csv

I've found numerous posts about reading CSV with Java and the APIs they were pointing at all had a line-oriented approach when it came to reading a CSV file. Something like "while you get a line, get the values of every column".

I'd appreciate a higher-level API, like in Perl where DBI allows you to use SQL on CSV like if it where a DB table. Otherwise I'll have to implement lots of access logic by myself.

Is there such an API? Am I missing something? There are some references about JDBC drivers but most are projects that haven't been updated the last 5 years.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [HSQL](http://hsqldb.org/) in order to do it, see the following links from the [docs](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch06.html) and a [blog post](http://www.java-community.de/archives/14-Use-HSQLDB-to-manipulate-CSV-data.html) describing exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

You could give [H2Database](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#csv) a go - it is rather heavy weight, but at least it is maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to avoid using a regular database for accessing CSV? MySQL supports CSV as one of it's table types if you are open to using a database system.

Answer (score -1):

yes, JDBC with a CSV driver. You can try implement yourself or just try something like [HXTT](http://www.hxtt.com/text.html)