# Filebased data service in Java

Tags: java, csv

I've found numerous posts about reading CSV with Java and the APIs they were pointing at all had a line-oriented approach when it came to reading a CSV file. Something like "while you get a line, get the values of every column".

Are there better ways to do that?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: How else would you do it ? If not you would need to read a buffer from the file, and parse the line end yourself and then parse the different fields in the line. The problem is keeping the lines in sync if you overflow the lines in the buffer. You might want to use a library like http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacsv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a database. Whether you write your own or use a third party one.
If not you will be doing sequential searches on your data to find anything.

You might want to look at this post: [Reading a CSV file into Java as a DB table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824565/reading-a-csv-file-into-java-as-a-db-table)

It looks like you have all the info you need.