# How to join 2 csv files in Java

Tags: java, sql, database, csv

I would like to be able to take 2 csv files as input, join them (SQL style) on a specific column, and output a new csv file which contains all file1 data, plus one of the columns of data from file2.

Any tips on what the best way to achieve this would be? Since SQL offerse the join command then possibly some method of treating the csv files as databases would work well, but I'm open to all suggestions really - the easiest wins.

All help is much appreciated!

Comment: This is actually the nicest solution I've found so far:
http://bayesianconspiracy.blogspot.com/2010/02/executing-arbitrary-sql-on-csv-files.html

Answer (score 0):

Do some simple file IO, split each line and load it into a Set type container.  Then you can do set type operations on the content of the two files:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/Setoperationsunionintersectiondifferencesymmetricdifferenceissubsetissuperset.htm

Answer (score 0):

you can parse your CSV files and bind them to the Beans with opencsv:
http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/
here, you can bind entities in CSV to a list of Beans: 
http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#javabean-integration

you can then do with List of Beans programmaticly what you want, like appending lists each other, or a join-like logic etc.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple, non-programmatic approach: import both text files into a spreadsheet, then use vlookup (or its equivalent) to look up values from one sheet into the other.

Answer (score 0):

For direct manipulation of CSV files as SQL tables see:
[Reading a CSV file into Java as a DB table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824565/reading-a-csv-file-into-java-as-a-db-table)

Answer (score 0):

You might also try to use a JDBC driver for CSV files like this one: 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/csvjdbc/

Answer (score 0):

I have written a command line program to execute arbitrary SQL on a csv files, including multi-file joins, called gcsvsql.  You can read about it here:

http://bayesianconspiracy.blogspot.com/2010/03/gcsvsql.html

There is a Google Code project for it here:  http://code.google.com/p/gcsvsql/

It's written in Java/Groovy, and will run anywhere Java is available.

Comment: If you're interested in doing this programmatically, from Groovy or Java, the [h2 database engine][1] is great for this. h2 forms the core of gcsvsql.  You can see examples of how use this programmatically here:

http://bayesianconspiracy.blogspot.com/2010/02/executing-arbitrary-sql-on-csv-files.html